# Data-equalizer only works when equalize_on_stack: true

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a website. On this website I've 3 floated divs next to each other, all with a 33% width. I'm trying to use data-equalizer on this, but it only works when equalize_on_stack is true. This while the divs aren't stacked.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thank you.

The code:

```
    <div class="small-12 large-8 column" data-equalizer>
        <div class="photoAlbumBox" >
            <p class="title">AFC fotoalbums</p>
            <div class="divider"></div>

            {foreach $homeblocks as $block}
                <a href="{$block->giveURL()}" target="_blank">
                    <div class="album" data-equalizer-watch>
                        <div class="photo">
                            <img src="{$block->getImg()}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <p class="date">Foto's <span>// {$block->c['date']|date_format:"%e %b %Y"}</span></p>
                            <p>{$block->c['msg']}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            {foreachelse}
                Er zijn nog geen foto's geplaatst...
            {/foreach}
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <a class="readmore" href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/126067985@N02/sets/" target="_blank">Bekijk alle foto's</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- COLUMN -->
```

Comment: I've gotten one step closer: the div's are being filled with a PHP foreach loop. This is all done server-side, so no AJAX-calls are being made. When I removed the PHP and just hardcore the divs, it works. Otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you are applying this? The parent container should have the attribute 'data-equalizer' and the children should have the attribute 'data-equalizer-watch'.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the 'data-equalizer' attribute to the parent container of the elements you wish to have equal heights.

In your case, it looks like you want the album div's to be equal height, so add the 'data-equalizer' to your a tag.

```
                <a href="" data-equalizer>// parent container
                  <div class="album" data-equalizer-watch>// child element
                    <div class="photo">
                      <img src="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
```

You can also give the 'data-equalizer' a unique name.

```
data-equalizer="equal-height"
data-equalizer-watch="equal-height"
```

Comment: The anchor isn't the parent. It gets repeated every time. The markup which I've is 100% correct.

Comment: Foundation just got strange bugs in their equalizer. I've had problems with things working on a local environment, but not on the live-version of the site and other weird stuff.